# Bootstrap 4 responsiveness for absolute positioned elements

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive

I would like to achieve this kind of screen in my web page. The absolute positioned element is yellow color container . I have written a media for each pixels which doesn't give a optimized responsiveness. Is there any class in bootstrap 4 to position like this and make it responsive across all the devices without have to write a media query explicitly? Thanks In Advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<style>
.sample{
  position:relative;
}

.ml-lg-1{
  position: absolute;
  top:25vh;
  left:-37vw;
}

@media (min-width:1340px){
.ml-lg-1{
position: absolute;
  top:25vh;
  left:-34vw;
  }
}
@media (min-width:1050px){
.ml-lg-1{
position: absolute;
  top:25vh;
  left:-36vw;
  }
}
@media (min-width:1100px){
.ml-lg-1{
position: absolute;
  top:25vh;
  left:-34vw;
  }
}
@media (min-width:1200px){
.ml-lg-1{
position: absolute;
  top:25vh;
  left:-37vw;
  }
}
@media (min-width:1300px){
.ml-lg-1{
position: absolute;
  top:25vh;
  left:-34vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1380px){
.ml-lg-1{
position: absolute;
  top:25vh;
  left:-31vw;
  }
}
@media (min-width:1705px){
.ml-lg-1{
position: absolute;
  top:25vh;
  left:-24vw;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container sample">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="columns col-sm-4" style="background:red;height:100vh;">
    First
    </div>
    <div class="columns col-sm-4" style="background:green;height:100vh;">
    Second
    </div>
    <div class="columns col-sm-4 third">
    Third
    <div class="container test ml-lg-1">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-4" style="background:yellow;height:100px;width:100px;">
         Test1
       </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>    
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is u r expected op

Comment: you probably require Nesting https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting

Comment: I want a output like above without have to write media queries explicitly. @AmareshSM please view the output in a full page You will come to know my intention

Comment: check out my answer @LakshmiS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `top` and `left` distance in `%`.

```
.ml-lg-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: -125%;
}
```

I hope this is what u r expecting.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<style>
.sample{
  position:relative;
}


.ml-lg-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: -125%;
}


</style>
<body>
<div class="container sample">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="columns col-sm-4" style="background:red;height:100vh;">
    First
    </div>
    <div class="columns col-sm-4" style="background:green;height:100vh;">
    Second
    </div>
    <div class="columns col-sm-4 third">
    Third
    <div class="container test ml-lg-1">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-4" style="background:yellow;height:100px;width:100px;">
         Test1
       </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>    
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I expected. Thank you again @AmareshSM

Answer (score 0):

I have only added two column but you can play with it and it give you the direction. there is no need for absolute positioning.
You can use the grid system as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col red">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col green">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 red">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 yellow">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 green">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col red">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col green">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the css:

```
    .row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.col- {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
```

[here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattopen/2hL6trmc/)

Comment: @LakshmiS and here is the link to the BS4 grid sources https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Hi. Matt I have gone thru the grid system. I want to achieve the output mentioned in my code. I have written media queries . I would like to avoid writing media queries to achieve that output. please view the output in a full page You will come to know my intention